# Standard ML binary tree datatype

Tags: binary-tree, sml, ml

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the answers in previous questions worked for me so I'll try a different approach.

I've done this:

```
> datatype which = STRING of string | INT of int;
datatype which = INT of int | STRING of string
> datatype whichTree = Empty | Leaf of which | Node of whichTree*whichTree;
datatype whichTree = Empty | Leaf of which | Node of whichTree * whichTree
```

but when I try to build a tree

```
> val mytree = Node(Leaf(which 2), Leaf(which 6));
```

I get errors.

```
Error-Value or constructor (which) has not been declared   Found near
Node( Leaf(which(2)), Leaf(which(6)))
Error-Value or constructor (which) has not been declared   Found near
Node( Leaf(which(2)), Leaf(which(6)))
Static errors (pass2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`which` is the name of the datatype; it's not a constructor. Instead, you have to create a tree as follows:

```
> val mytree = Node(Leaf(INT 2), Leaf(STRING "6"));
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the help. I guess I still have a lot to learn about ML